# What is the correct procedure when "joining" data takes ~6 hours?

Tags: dataset, bigdata, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I am dealing with bike-share data. I have 2 `DataFrames`:

1. `trips_df` *(subset shown)*, total entries = `1,048,568`

[image]

2. `weather_df` *(subset shown)*, total entries = `2,654`

[image]

I am trying to calculate and attach the `total_precipitation` for each trip, as a column. I do this by looking up the `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` datetime for each trip from `trips_df`, in the `weather_df`, and summing the `precipitation_amount` within those times, then attaching that value back in the `trips_df` under the new column. I can attach the code if it's helpful.

I ran the code on a subset of 65 entries and it took ~1.3s. (`CPU times: user 1.27 s, sys: 8.77 ms, total: 1.28 s, Wall time: 1.28 s`). Extrapolating that performance to my entire data, it would take (1.3 * 1048568)/65 = 20971.36seconds or 5.8hours.

What am I supposed to do in this situation? For context, this is a Kaggle style data science project so I'll have to do further data wrangling, and data extraction then apply a predictive model.

Comment: Is it recommended that I randomly sample `n` amount of entries from `trips_df` and use that?

Comment: Yes code would be helpful. How are you doing the timestamp lookup? Is the weather data hourly and complete? Is it all one location? Can you convert the weather data to hours-since-hour-0 so its a column of 0 to (n-1), do the same for trips and then its a row-index? Are your timestamps character and so you are spending all the time doing char-date conversion? Since you asked this 16 hours ago have you done this already now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted at by @spacedman I was doing the timestamp lookups wrong.

I was forming a `set(weather_data['start_precipitation_datetime'])` and `set(weather_data['end_precipitation_datetime'])` for *every* lookup. Here is the working (more efficient) code.

`CPU times: user 118 ms, sys: 4.23 ms, total: 122 ms
Wall time: 124 ms` for 65 rows. Roughly 35minutes instead of 6hours for the entire `DataFrame`.

```py
def sum_precipitation(datetime1, datetime2, weather_data, start_dates_set, end_dates_set):

    time1_rd = datetime1.replace(minute=0, second=0)
    time2_ru = datetime2.replace(minute=0, second=0) + dt.timedelta(hours=1)

    if time1_rd in set_start:

        start_idx = weather_data.start_precipitation_datetime[
            weather_data.start_precipitation_datetime==time1_rd].index[0]

        if time2_ru in set_end:

            end_idx = weather_data.end_precipitation_datetime[
                weather_data.end_precipitation_datetime==time2_ru].index[0]

            precipitation_sum = weather_data.iloc[start_idx:end_idx+1, 7].sum()

        else: precipitation_sum = 0
    else: precipitation_sum = 0

    return round(precipitation_sum, 3)

def join_weather_to_trips(trips_data, weather_data):

    trips_weather_df = trips_data.copy()

    start_hr_set = set(weather_data['start_precipitation_datetime'])
    end_hr_set = set(weather_data['end_precipitation_datetime'])

    fn = lambda row : sum_precipitation(row.start_timestamp, row.end_timestamp, weather_data, 
                                        start_hr_set, end_hr_set)
    col = trips_data.apply(fn, axis=1)
    trips_weather_df = trips_weather_df.assign(total_precipitation=col.values)

    return trips_weather_df
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no ideal way of doing that type of join efficiently in Pandas.

One possible option is using [numpy.piecewise](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) to define matches based on the timestamps from each dataframe. An example of apply numpy.piecewise can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328014/merging-dataframes-based-on-date-range).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check if a timestamp from the weather data is within your trip timestamps, then change the weather timestamps to match the trip timestamp. After that merge both data frames on the timestamp columns. Then use group_by().sum() to aggregate on the timestamps and sum up the precipitation column. Now take the summed up precipitation column and append it to your initial trip dataframe.